# Rewriting a CI url

Tags: php, codeigniter, url-rewriting

I have never before rewritten a URL except for removing the index.php part of my CodeIgniter installs, and that I do by using a copy-pasted snippet in my .htaccess file. I haven't had the time to actually learn about what the snippet does; I'm basically very new to rewriting URLs.

I have a mobile version of my web application. I got as far as redirecting mobile users to a subdomain: `m.myhost.tld`. However, since I'm using (one) CodeIgniter (install), I have to send these mobile users to a mobile-specific controller, in my case `/mobile/`. So, the controller always shows up in my address bar.

I just don't think this is very clean, and I'm looking for a way to rewrite the URL; but truth be told, I'm not even sure if this is possible.. hence my question. 
I want to get rid of the `/mobile` controller part. Is this possible?

Some examples:

My current  mobile 'root' folder is

`http://m.myhost.tld/mobile`

I would like to turn this one into

`http://m.myhost.tld/`

At the moment, when I go to `http://m.myhost.tld/`, it redirects to the default controller for my CodeIgniter application, which is part of the 'desktop' version of the web app.

Another example:

Turning

`http://m.myhost.tld/mobile#mobile/about`

into

`http://m.myhost.tld/#mobile/about`

I'm not sure if I'm making any sense here. I am in my head, but like I said, I don't know what exactly **is possible**. If the user is on the `m` subdomain, I want to hide the `/mobile` part of my URLs. However, only when we're on the `m` subdomain, so the 'desktop' version (which sits at `www` ) does not get touched at all.

Like I said a couple of times now, I'm not sure what is possible and what I'm looking for might just be too complex or whatnot. I figured I would ask though, since learning by asking is what I do best. Please don't be too hard on me if this turns out to be a dumb question, sirs professionals ;)

EDIT:
I thought I'd edit because I don't want to come off wrong. I'm not necessarily looking for exact answers to my question. I also welcome documentation/tutorials/articles that might guide me to a solution. If I can manage to come up with a solution of my own, I will of course learn a lot more.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be too simple of a solution but why not in your routing config do something simple like

in your config do something like

```
if ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == 'm.myhost.tld')
    $route['default_controller'] = "mobile";
```

This would make the default controller mobil so you wouldn't have to have /mobile...

As i said maybe too simple

Comment: Ohh. I'm honestly getting fed up with myself, always looking far too hard. I'm always trying to make it more difficult than it actually is. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: Doesn't work, but maybe someone can turn it into something that does**

Try this:

```
RewriteCond $1!^mobile/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^m\.myhost\.tld
RewriteRule (.*) /mobile/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks, doesn't seem to work though. I suppose there's a small typo in your answer? `%{HTTP_HOST}`. But then it still doesn't work; I get a huge 403 error: You don't have permission to access /index.php//mobile/index.php/mobile/index.php/mobile/index/...(and so on for a bit) on this server.

Comment: Ah yah, that makes sense - it's just an infinite redirect. That will teach me to answer questions on SO this early in the morning :D I'm going to go ahead and delete it and if I come up with something else I'll post it.

Comment: I edited my original answer to add a condition that should ensure that it doesn't redirect infinitely. Give it a shot and let me know if it works.

Comment: It returns an Internal Server Error :( Not sure how to debug this?

Comment: Well, I tried. I don't have access to Apache at the moment, so if I haven't seen anything else come up by the time I get home from work I'll take another shot at it.

Comment: I had absolutely zero luck with this, so I wish you the best of luck.

Comment: Thanks again for your time. It turned out to be a lot more simple than I thought it would be.. :( Thanks.